# stuck on tty, black startx, unable to locate package ubuntu-dekstop

Tags: boot, nvidia, tty

I'm posting this question using my tablet since I cannot use my laptop normally. 
2 days before I installed wine and picasa, photoscape, and some other windows app. Usually I didnot shutdown my laptop, only closing it so let it sleep. Yesterday i click on restart to complete update, when the system boot it appear: low-graphic mode. This had happened before, when i try update wrong nvidia drivers.

So i enter into tty. Before, i've tried to boot into grub menu, but when i press shift, nothing happens. And i found out that others also having this problem, not being able to get into grub menu and choose recovery mode.

Then i tried sudo apt-get update, it didn't work. I tried sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* and then sudo apt-get update, and it works. Then i tried sudo install --reinstall ubuntu-dekstop, it didn't work. It says unable to locate package ubuntu-dekstop.

Then i tried many things, install nvidia-current, it worked. Install gnome, the installation not complete due to problems with some packages.

I've tried switch to lihtgdm, also didn't work. Tried install and update gdm, didn't solve a thing. Now i'm stuck with this tty, when i prompt startx it bring me a balck screen. Whenever i boot it after shutdown, it will just bring me to tty. But i don't have any problems with apt-get uodate.

Now i have two major problems:

1. On boot startup, i got three lines of efidisk read error.
2. I'm unable to install ubuntu-dekstop.

I really need to do works on my laptop. after this i will try to boot with live cd, but this will take time because i have to download and burn another cd. Just to make sure, booting with live cd won't make me lose my data right?

so meanwhile, please give me your opinions and help. I really need my laptop to work as usual. I really have tried a lot

I also tried ubuntu-session. The first time i have this problem with low graphic mode, i switched to tty, do sudo apt-get update, then install ubuntu-dekstop, startx and it worked. I'm only running on ubuntu 12.04, but not sure which partition i use

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. If it wasn't able to locate it during a reinstall, chances are it was somehow uninstalled.

Comment: Already done. But the weird thing is i don't have ptoblems with apt-get update.

Comment: Try purging and reinstalling `unity`.

Comment: Done, then i tried to install ubuntu dekstop and still couldn' locate package

Comment: Wait, `ubuntu-desktop` can't be found? It sounds like you disabled a source.

Comment: I've tried to boot with a live cd, but it can't be done. I save the boot option for live cd, but after reboot the ubuntu installation menu doesn't appear and the screen remain black. When i remove the cd, i get into tty again